# Как получить скриншот окна игры Unity3D в виде base64 строки?

Tags: c#, unity3d, screenshots

подскажите пожалуйста как можно с помощью C# скрипта на Unity Engine
Сделать скриншот и перевести его в в строку base64
При этом мне не нужно сохранять его в виде файла как это делает Application.CaptureScreenshot(fileName)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно через текстуру

```
public class TakeScreenShot : MonoBehaviour
{
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(TakeSnapshot());//Выполняем, когда хотим сделать скриншот, например по нажатию кнопки
}

WaitForEndOfFrame endOfCurrenFrame = new WaitForEndOfFrame();//Для того, чтобы дождаться окончания текущего кадра

public IEnumerator TakeSnapshot()
{
    yield return endOfCurrenFrame;

    Texture2D screenImage = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, true);
    screenImage.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
    screenImage.LoadRawTextureData(screenImage.GetRawTextureData());
    screenImage.Apply();
    string image64 = TextureTo64(screenImage);//Тут переводим текстуру в строку
}


public static string TextureTo64(Texture2D texture)
{
    byte[] imageData = texture.EncodeToPNG();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(imageData);
}

}
```